# Dynamic values dynamic array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, dynamic

I have database MySQL and in one of the tables fields I have a suggestions which have values like this "13095,11413,11424,11434" or "1344,14513,11423"

The number in the values are my productID, ok now I need to do a while loop for each number and print it in a table, I can do the while loop to retrieve the product information, but how could I get the numbers each one alone to do the retrieving? I thought that if I used array I may solve the problem I used

PHP:

```
$sug = $row['SuggestProduct'];  
$asug = array($sug);
```

but here `array[0] = "13095,11413,11424,11434"`

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is your friend.

Comment: `$asug = explode(',', $row['SuggestProduct']);`

Comment: orb: submit that as an answer, IMO.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: If something is simple enough to put in a small comment, it never seems worth bothering with a full answer.  Mel seems to have covered it well enough anyhow.

Comment: No idea why there is a downvote on this, a first question at that - the question is entirely fine and sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While explode is your friend, you should consider storing the suggestions differently. Do some research on "many to many" relations.
Solution for the above program is `$suggestions = explode(',', $row['SuggestProduct']);`

Comment: but how i can get the data, its stored in $suggestions, but $suggestions is an array or what?

Comment: yes, explode returns an array. Orbling linked the function for you, so read up on what it does.

Comment: i need the data like this:  
$item1 = 13095;  
$item2 = 11413;  
$item3 = 11424;  
$item4 = 11434;  
  
or any thing like that, how could i take each number alone??